# What is $\zeta(n)$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$? How fast it goes to the limit?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

What is $\zeta(n)$ as $n\to\infty$? How fast it goes to the limit?

Comment: The limit is 1.

Comment: The sequence is monotonically decreasing and is in the interval [1, \zeta(2)]. Hence it is convergent. My guess is that this goes to 1.

Comment: @ozo How? Can you give a complete proof?

Comment: It follows from the dominated convergence theorem for series.

Comment: @user41481 your guess is right. You also haven't accepted the answer below. Is there something in particular more you're hoping to get out of an answer which I could add to improve it?

Answer (score 6):

Absolute convergence in the right half-plane (standard for all Dirichlet series, but if you're unsure, you can compare via

$$\zeta(\sigma)<\zeta(2)\quad\forall \sigma >2$$

by just comparing term-by-term)

Then you take the limit inside, giving you

$$\lim_{\sigma\to\infty}\zeta(\sigma)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\lim_{\sigma\to\infty}n^{-\sigma}\right)=1+0+0+\ldots$$

In particular

it's easy to see by the same absolute convergence that

$$\zeta(\sigma)-1={2^\sigma\over 2^\sigma}\sum_{n=2}^\infty n^{-\sigma}=2^{-\sigma}\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left({2\over n}\right)^\sigma\sim 2^{-\sigma}$$

the last asymptotic comes from

$$\lim_{\sigma\to\infty}\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left({2\over n}\right)^\sigma =\sum_{n=2}^\infty \lim_{\sigma\to\infty}\left({2\over n}\right)^\sigma = 1+0+0+\ldots$$

from the same argument as we used on $\zeta(\sigma)\stackrel{\sigma\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}1$, where we take the limit inside and the first term is $1$, and each subsequent term goes to $0$.

Comment: That same line of argument also produces $\zeta(n)-1\sim~2^{-n}$ as $n\to\infty$. So it converges rapidly as well.

Comment: Thanks, @Semiclassical, I didn't originally see the op asking for that in his question.

Comment: @Adam Hughes   The $\lim_\sigma \sum =\sum\lim_\sigma$ assertion does not follow because the series is absolutely convergent, but because it converges uniformly in $\sigma\geq2$.